# SignalR pinging clients

Tags: asp.net, signalr

I feel like I'm getting mixed reviews about SignalR and disconnection functionality and I'm trying to figure out who is right (these packages move so fast it's hard to tell what is right information these days since something you find online could be 2 months old and outdated).

I've seen many people setup pinging code to tell if a client is still connected. Yet I see others talking about the Disconnect() function that gets fired from the Hub when a client disconnects. Then I see some say the Disconnect() method isn't reliable?

Does anyone have the details on this as it stands today? Should I not be using the Disconnect() method because in some cases (which maybe I haven't ran into yet) it's not reliable? It's so confusing trying to search for information when these things change so often invalidating older information you find on the web about it.

Answer (score 2):

There might be a couple of edge cases where you don't get timely notifications but in general it is reliable. Also, we raise disconnect events on the client as well and we have a keep alive functionality which ensures that if the client doesn't hear from the server within a specified timeout, we will try to reconnect and ultimately disconnect if reconnects fail. Therefore, you can take appropriate actions on the client.

You can read more about this here http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-server#connectionlifetime